# an empty record is created, how can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my online shop I would like that a user could start shopping without an account, he could select items and add them to his cart.
He would create his account just before the payment process, if he doesn't have any account yet.

Also I would like that **order belongs_to user**

In my **order.rb** I added,

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

So I can create the **order** without **user_id**.
I update the **order** with the **user_id** in the payment create method.
I need this association because I want to retrieve users' orders.

In my **application_controller.rb** I have a method that set a cart

```
before_action :current_cart

def current_cart
    @current_cart ||= ShoppingCart.new(token: cart_token)
end
helper_method :current_cart

private

     def cart_token
       return @cart_token unless @cart_token.nil?
       session[:cart_token] ||= SecureRandom.hex(8)
       @cart_token = session[:cart_token]
     end
```

Once my user have paid, his **order** is recorded.
Also I found out that as I don't force the association with the user and the order, an empty order is created because of the current_cart in the application_controller...

here is the **shopping_cart.rb** model

```
class ShoppingCart

  delegate :sub_total, to: :order

  def initialize(token:)
    @token = token
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.find_or_create_by(token: @token, status: 0) do |order|
      order.sub_total = 0
    end
  end

  def items_count
    order.items.sum(:quantity)
  end

  def add_item(product_id:, quantity:1 , size_id:) 
    @product = Product.find(product_id)
    @size = Size.find_by(id: size_id)

    @order_item =  if order.items.where(product_id: product_id).where(size_id: size_id).any?
       order.items.find_by(product_id: product_id, size_id: size_id)
    else
     order.items.new(product_id: product_id, size_id: size_id)
    end

    @order_item.price = @product.price_cents
    @order_item.quantity = quantity.to_i

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @order_item.save
      update_sub_total!
    end
    CartCleanupJob.set(wait: 1.minutes).perform_later(order.id)
  end

  def change_qty(id:, quantity:1, product_id:, size_id:)
    @size = Size.find_by(id: size_id)
    @order_item = order.items.find_by(product_id: product_id, size_id: size_id)
    @order_item.quantity = quantity.to_i
    @order_item.save
    update_sub_total!
  end

  def remove_item(id:)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      order.items.destroy(id)
      update_sub_total!
    end
  end

  private

  def update_sub_total!
    order.sub_total = order.items.sum('quantity * price')
    order.save
  end


end
```

What should I do in order that my user can create his account right before the payment, and not to have an empty order created...?

Comment: Can you use find_or_initialize_by in your order method of you ShoppingCart class?  That will call new rather than create.

Comment: ohhh I skipped that ! many thanks ! You can provide an answer I will accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the order method of your ShoppingCart class, you use `find_or_create_by` which as the name implies,  call the `create` method of the Order class .  If you switch to find_or_initialize_by instead the `new` method will be called giving you an Order object, but not created in the database.

```
  def order
    @order ||= Order.find_or_initialize_by(token: @token, status: 0) do |order|
      order.sub_total = 0
    end
  end
```